# Convert array pointer to void* at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have this code:

```
template <const void*, class Type, size_t Size>
Type GetNextElementImpl(const Type (&Array)[Size])
{
    static int index = -1;
    index = (index + 1) % Size;
    return Array[index];
}
```

Since this is used in several places around the codebase, the function needs to have a unique index for each array that it is used with. The const void* is there in the template parameters to make a unique instantiation for each usage. Regular usage would be like this:

```
int TestArray1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int TestArray2[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
int item1 = GetNextElementImpl<TestArray1>(TestArray1); // item is 0
int item2 = GetNextElementImpl<TestArray2>(TestArray2); // item is 10, not 20
```

Using a macro makes usage nicer:

```
#define GetNextElement(StaticArray) GetNextElementImpl<StaticArray>(StaticArray)
int item = GetNextElement(TestArray);
```

Works fine in MSVC, but GCC seems to have a problem converting the static array type to a const void pointer. I tried reinterpret_cast<>, but got another error about non-integer operations at compile time. Is there any way to convert a pointer to a known type to a void pointer at compile time?

Comment: I don't see any conversion to `void*` (or any reason to do any) in your example... Please provide the code and rationale for the conversion.

Comment: AFAIK gcc is right, `reinterpret_cast`s are not allowed in constant expressions as of [expr.const]/2. Can you use C++11 features like `decltype`?

Comment: Why aren't you using a template class typed by the array? Holding the index state would be trivial.

Comment: This is the wrong approach to whatever you're trying to do. Do what Jason suggests: just make a class that stores the array (by reference if you want) and the current index, then have a member that fetches-and-increments by index. Global state is to be avoided, especially state that you have to hide behind a macro...

Comment: @DyP: Unfortunately, no, I have to support multiple compilers, some of which have no C++11 support.

Comment: @Jason: Yeah that's a good idea. I was mostly trying to upgrade and reuse existing functionality, but I guess I might as well change the whole thing.

Comment: Have you tried using static_cast? Or is it possible to just use a C style cast? What you can do should be possible, even with a stubborn g++ compiler, with a little bit of coaxing.